# Accessing field in var that has oracle query results

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have the following:

```
var conn = new DataStore(_db.ConnectionStrings.First(p => p.Name == "OracleConn").Value);
var results = conn .ExecuteQuery(_oracleQuery).Tables[0].AsEnumerable();

if (results.Count() > 0)
{
  var record = results.First();

  var result = new
  {
     success = true,
     personId= QueryParse.ToString(record["personId"])
     };
   }
```

The stored procedure (_oracleQuery) is:

```
SELECT personID from People
```

I have the following:

```
foreach (var person in _db.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.LastUpdated))
    {
        data.Add(new List<string>
        {
            person.UserId,
            person.FullName,
            person.Title
        }    
    }
```

but need to add the oracle query into there, and if the id exists, so 'Y', else show 'N'.
I can't add this though:

```
(results.Where(p => p.personID== person.personId).FirstOrDefault() == null? "N" : "Y")
```

as I get the following error message:

'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'personID' and no extension method 'personID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like results is some form of Enumerable of DataRows.
As we see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) DataRow doesn't have any method or property called personId. That's what gives you the error when you write p.personID

That means you have to use your column name to get your value like you already did before and make sure you're casting correctly for the sake of comparison.

```
(results.Where(p => (int)p["personId"] == person.personId).FirstOrDefault() == null? "N" : "Y")
```

Now, it will grab the personId from the p dataRow when you write p["personId"] and cast is an int, so you can properly compare it to whatever is in person.personId. I would also suggest rewriting your linq query so you can use .Any() to make it more readable.

```
results.Any(p =>  (int)p["personId"] == person.personId) ? "Y" : "N";
```

I hope that makes sense.